# How to transfer config of one mailman list to another?

Tags: configuration, mailman

I want to transfer one mailman list from one server to another. I guess the old config is in the mailman\lists\LISTNAME\config.pck file, but i can't read it and I don't want to blind copy files around without knowing what I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
old-server% config_list -o foo oldlistname
```

check foo to make sure it's got no server-specific stuff in it.  copy the file across to new-server.

```
new-server% config_list -i foo newlistname
```

Comment: Could we not have this discussion here, please?  The OP doesn't ask how to transfer the membership or their passwords, only the config.  If you want to know how to copy more than that, ask that question separately (maybe linking to this one, to avoid duplicating it).

Comment: This doesn't transfer the list password, nor any members.

Comment: @MadHatter: It wasn't clear to me whether the config included the members, and I'm not sure whether it was clear to the OP. Hence my remark.

Comment: @reinierpost since the OP accepted this answer, and did so a decade ago, I think we may conclude that (s)he is satisfied.  I upvoted your comment pointing out the issue with list members, because I thought it a useful clarification, but that doesn't modify the question.

Comment: Questions and answers are for general use. I was confused. Your suggestion to create [a separate question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1042146/how-to-transfer-membership-properties-from-one-mailman-list-to-another) is much appreciated.

Comment: Today I was seaching for advice to copy a mailinglist, actually I want to implement a renaming. This question was suggested by google, so a hint about the limits is useful in my opinion.BTW: this could be of value https://mail.python.org/pipermail/mailman-users/2005-July/045647.html

Comment: @Wolf I'm not saying you're wrong to want that, I'm saying this question doesn't want it, and you *are* wrong to try to read this question as if it does.  Fortunately, reinierpost has opened a new question to pick up all those other details, so hopefully that - along with this one - will become what you need.