# How to transfer membership properties from one mailman list to another?

Tags: copy, mailman

Mailman lacks support for renaming a list. I need a workaround (lists do need to be renamed).

We can create a new list, [copy its config](https://serverfault.com/questions/194450/how-to-transfer-config-of-one-mailman-list-to-another), and subscribe all members of the old list to the new one (using the `list_members` and `add_members` command line utilities), but that doesn't copy any of the members' properties, such as passwords.

How to do that? The code base for Mailman 2.1.26 (as distributed by Ubuntu) doesn't appear to support it, but it's Python; any third-party attempts or insights on how to do it anyway are welcome.

Comment: Just a reminder that we already have an answer for [copying the config](https://serverfault.com/questions/194450/how-to-transfer-config-of-one-mailman-list-to-another/194460?noredirect=1#comment1356638_194460), so this question is specific to copying the membership, member passwords, and anything else that's not picked up by a simple config copy.

Comment: Maybe explicitly referencing the config question here would be better to show that you are aware of the relation between both.